# Image blurring results in a sharp edge

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm doing some processing with MATLAB on an RGB image.
I had to obtain a circular blurring like in the image below:

[image]

obtained through this code:

```
A = imread('lena .bmp');
I = rgb2gray(A);

[rNum,cNum,~] = size(I);   

%center and radius of the circular mask 
x1 = 256.5;
y1 = 256.5;
radius = 100;

%circular mask creation 
[x,y] = ndgrid((1:rNum)-y1,(1:cNum)-x1);   
mask = (x.^2 + y.^2)<radius^2;             

h = ones(30,30)/900;           %gaussian filter 

J = roifilt2(h,I,mask);        %apply the filter at the mask 


%filtering plane - by - plane in order to apply the circular blurred mask
%to the RGB image 

filtered_im = zeros(size(A));
filtered_im(:,:,1) = roifilt2(h, A(:,:,1), mask);
filtered_im(:,:,2) = roifilt2(h, A(:,:,2), mask);
filtered_im(:,:,3) = roifilt2(h, A(:,:,3), mask);
filtered_im = uint8(filtered_im); 
figure
imshow(filtered_im) 
title('Circular blurring RGB image');
```

The effect obtained, anyway, is too artificial because the transition between the blurred circular mask and the rest of the image is too sharp. Is there a possibility to make this transition more faded in order to obtain a more natural effect?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a weighted average of both the original image and the modified one, using as weights a mask based on the distance to the center of the circle.
The original one would have more weight in the external part of the circle, and the modified image in the center. This could create a transition in the blurring.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try as you have suggested.